# Unable to place view below RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm having trouble placing an `Adview` below a `RecyclerView`. Currently the `RecyclerView` is taking up the rest of the layout and the `Adview` isn't being shown. None of the solutions I have found online have solved my issue. Usually `layout_weight` or `layout_below` solves the problem but it isn't in this case.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#7c7c7c"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relContainer"
            android:background="@drawable/bordershadow2"
            android:paddingBottom="17dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bordershadow"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

           <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/purchaseTableLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/typeSpinner"
                        style="style/Theme.Material"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:entries="@array/type_array"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/purchaseTableLayout"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'() "
                android:hint="Search"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/searchEditText"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="3.0">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/sortRaceSpinner"
                        style="style/Theme.Material"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:entries="@array/sort_race_array"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/sortAffinitySpinner"
                        style="style/Theme.Material"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:entries="@array/sort_affinity_array"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
                        style="style/Theme.Material"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:entries="@array/sort_array"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I rewrote your layout file, The recycleview is wrapped inside a linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/wrapper"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="60dp"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:clipToPadding="false"
       android:paddingBottom="20dp"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingTop="10dp" />

   </LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/wrapper"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/purchaseTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/typeSpinner"
                style="style/Theme.Material"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/purchaseTableLayout"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'() "
        android:hint="Search"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3.0">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sortRaceSpinner"
                style="style/Theme.Material"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sortAffinitySpinner"
                style="style/Theme.Material"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
                style="style/Theme.Material"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is as show

[image]

If your recycleview content will extend beyond the display height then you should consider dividing your layout into partitions with android:layout_weight.

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/purchaseTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/typeSpinner"
                style="style/Theme.Material"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/purchaseTableLayout"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'() "
        android:hint="Search"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3.0">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sortRaceSpinner"
                style="style/Theme.Material"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sortAffinitySpinner"
                style="style/Theme.Material"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
                style="style/Theme.Material"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relContainer"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrappers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Just tried it out but the recycler view doesnt expand past 60dp. I'm using a recycler adapter which might be cause the issue

Comment: Sorry, change the android:layout_height="60dp" to wrap_content in the Linear_layout

Comment: Now the recycler view takes up the rest of the layout again

Comment: Oh and the spinners are suppose to be on top of the recylerview

Comment: Check my comment, if the recycleview content covers the whole Layout then You have to use a LinearLayout to partition section like - Spinner, recycler and Adview. I will update my layout.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I will try the layout when you update it.

Comment: Hi Henry, I read your blog post here https://inducesmile.com/android/android-firebaseui-with-custom-firebaserecycleradapter-example-tutorial/ and was wondering if you could help with this Firebase issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134470/recyclerview-in-fragment-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout

Answer (score 11):

I had a view that needed to be under a recycler view with dynamic size.
meaning that the view supposes to move down as the RecyclerView grew.

my solution was to add paddingBottom to the RecyclerView and then negative marginTop in the same value to the view, it worked perfectly.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:paddingBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nice and simple solution

Comment: Well done this really is a good solution even though it feels like a hack :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `android:clipToPadding="false"` attribute to your RecyclerView.

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setClipToPadding(boolean)) says, about clipToPadding:

> Sets whether this ViewGroup will clip its children to its padding and
>   resize (but not clip) any EdgeEffect to the padded region, if padding
>   is present.
>
> By default, children are clipped to the padding of their parent
>   ViewGroup. This clipping behavior is only enabled if padding is
>   non-zero.

---

Your XML layout would end up being:

**layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relContainer"
    android:background="@drawable/bordershadow2"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it other way, put the Adview on the recycler at the bottom and then in the adapter add an empty ViewHolder which will be always your last element, you can use for it an empty layout with the height of Adview.