# RecyclerView in Fragment - No Adapter Attached, Skipping Layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an odd situation, I have an `Activity` hosting a `TabLayout/Viewpager` that populates data based on changes to a Firebase Database. Unfortunately, the `RecyclerView` is not being populated, and I am receiving the error below in my logcat. I believe the fragment is being loaded even when it is not on screen, which is causing an error in the population of the `RecyclerView`. It is also weird as the `RecyclerView` does populate when I rotate the screen:

```
12-13 21:31:40.013 12490-12490/com.troychuinard.fanpolls E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Here is the `ViewPager` Adapter I have in my host `Activity`:

```
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new TrendingFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FollowingFragment();
            case 2:
                return new LiveFragment();
            default:
                return new TrendingFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.trending_text);
            case 1:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.following_text);
            case 2:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.new_text);
            default:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.trending_text);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the complete fragment where I initialize the `RecyclerView` inside `onCreateView()` function in my `LiveFragment`, which is tab 3 in the `TabLayout`:

```
public class LiveFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
private DatabaseReference mBaseRef;
private DatabaseReference mPollsRef;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Poll, PollHolder> mFireAdapter;


// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public LiveFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment LiveFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static LiveFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    LiveFragment fragment = new LiveFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mPollsRef = mBaseRef.child("Polls");

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container, false);
    Log.v("TAG", "ON CREATE CALLED FROM NEW");

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    mRecyclerview = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.new_RecyclerView);

    if (mRecyclerview != null){
        mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    if (mRecyclerview == null){
       Log.v("TAG", "RECYCLERVIEW NULL");
    } else if (mLayoutManager == null){
        Log.v("TAG", "LAYOUTMANAGER NULL");
    } else if (mFireAdapter == null) {
        Log.v("TAG", "mFIREADAPTER NULL");
    }
    return v;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mFireAdapter != null){
        mFireAdapter.cleanup();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mFireAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Poll, PollHolder>(Poll.class, R.layout.latest_item, PollHolder.class, mPollsRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PollHolder viewHolder, Poll model, int position) {
            viewHolder.mPollQuestion.setText(model.getQuestion());
            Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                    .load(model.getImage_URL())
                    .fit()
                    .into(viewHolder.mPollImage);
            Log.v("QUESTION", model.getQuestion());
            Log.v("IMAGE", model.getImage_URL());
        }
    };
    mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mFireAdapter);

    mPollsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot x : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                mFireAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });





}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


public static class PollHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView mPollQuestion;
    ImageView mPollImage;


    public PollHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mPollQuestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.latest_item_question);
        mPollImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pollThumbNailImage);

    }
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your Adapter from onCreateView to onActivityCreated method after you have read data from firebase.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

//read Poll data from firebase mPollsRef for example
//.... database reference to firebase
//Query mPollsRef = databaseReference.child("pools").limitToFirst(200);


    mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mFireAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Poll, PollHolder>(Poll.class, R.layout.latest_item, PollHolder.class, mPollsRef) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(PollHolder viewHolder, Poll model, int position) {
        viewHolder.mPollQuestion.setText(model.getQuestion());
        Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                .load(model.getImage_URL())
                .fit()
                .into(viewHolder.mPollImage);
        Log.v("QUESTION", model.getQuestion());
        Log.v("IMAGE", model.getImage_URL());
        }
    };
    mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mFireAdapter);

}
```

My code for initialize Pager at HostActivity.java

```
private FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_absence);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each section
    mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        private final Fragment[] mFragments = new Fragment[] {
                new MyAbsenceFragment(),
                new MyAttendanceFragment(),
                new AbsTypesFragment(),
                new LiveFragment(),
        };
        private final String[] mFragmentNames = new String[] {
                "Absences",
                "Attendances",
                "AbsTypes",
                "Live"
        };
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments[position];
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.length;
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentNames[position];
        }
    };
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: Are you assuming I have to write Firebase code? I believe the Firebase adapter handles that, so I am not sure what I would write...it ended up not working either way

Comment: Yes, you have to write code for mPollsRef, that you commit to your FBadapter. For example https://github.com/eurosecom/Attendance/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eusecom/attendance/fragment/AbsenceListFragment.java and https://github.com/eurosecom/Attendance/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eusecom/attendance/fragment/MyAbsenceFragment.java and https://github.com/eurosecom/Attendance/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eusecom/attendance/viewholder/AbsenceViewHolder.java.

Comment: Got it, so based on my code above, do you understand why my view is not appearing on my fragment?

Comment: I don't know all your code. Write your solving, please.

Comment: I have added the complete fragment. I do appreciate your help. Getting really frustrated with this as I cannot figure it out...

Comment: Nice solution for firebase fragments. I've enjoyed cooperating. Good luck.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean I was frustrated with you. Just with the problem in general

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't understand. I've thought everything is OK. I've put LiveFragment.java to my AndroidStudio and it work. May be problem at HostActivity.java by initialize Pager. I use code above, watch edited answer. Try to change or show HostActivity.code. What's logcat by initialize LiveFragment ?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. When you load the fragment are you seeing items in the RecyclerView? Can you post your FragmentPagerAdapter code?

Comment: Yes i see items. I use import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter. Oncreate method my HostPagerActivity.java is above in my answer. Complet code my hostactivity here https://github.com/eurosecom/Attendance/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eusecom/attendance/AbsenceActivity.java

Comment: Much appreciated!