# How to refresh data in ViewPager Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need to know the life-cycle of the Fragments inside ViewPager?
I have a ViewPager of 3 tabs (3 Fragments )
What is the life-cycle while swiping between them ?

I notice that when i go from Fragment 3 to Fragment 1 , it is being refreshed. so which method in the life-cycle is called in this moment?

I tried to put Toast inside every method, but i found that they are called after each other so i did`t know which one is responsible for refreshing.

I guess it`s onActivityCreated() ,  but to call it i must pass Bundle saveInstancestate. When i pass null it crashes, so how to get this object ?

If there any other/better approach to do so, please share.
The goal is to refresh the data inside the fragment when i click on button in the actionbar.

Thanks

Comment: Does the `getItem` method of the Pager adapter create new instances of the fragments?

Comment: it does nothing

Comment: What do you mean does nothing? It has to return a View or a Fragment (probably a Fragment, in your case).

Comment: i call it when i click the refresh button but it does nothing, i`m not sure what you mean

Comment: When you go from 1 to 3, your Fragment 1 got detached and be destroyed, Its state is saved too. So after you go from 3 to 1, your Adapter create Fragment 1 again from scratch with saved state. In short, all life cycle event happens.

Comment: You attached a PagerAdapter to the ViewPager, I assume. That's how ViewPager's work. The PagerAdapter class has a `getItem(int position)` method

Comment: If you want to keep it alive, search for "PagerAdapter OffsetLimit", if you want to know which event has been triggered, simply put a Log call (not Toast).

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam can i hold the saved state?

Comment: For what? It is automatically passed in your onCreate/onCreateView ... and so on.

Comment: yes i override it in the adapter but when i call it outside the adpater (inside button onClick) it does nothing

Comment: FYI just yesterday I debug my app using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, so have no idea about FragmentPagerAdapter (have not used it for years).

Comment: Okay, you override it, so if you `return new ExampleFragment()`, then the entire lifecycle will be called as Fragments are destroyed (as explained in the answer below)

Answer (score 1):

A view pager fragment always loads its neighbors on either side.

Because of this you will see the creation callbacks for the fragments run before they are visible. After you are 2 pages away from a fragment it will be destroyed.

Have your activity implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` then use  `onPageSelected` to get the call into your fragment.  You can keep references to the view page fragments in that activity.

```
 public class ViewPagerActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
           //Restore the fragment's instance
           mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
           ...
        }
        ...
    }

   @Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

      //Save the fragment's instance
      getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
    }


    // regular activity stuff plus view pager methods

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
       final ReadyFragment fragment = mAdapter.getItem(arg0);
       if (fragment.isVisible()) {
          fragment.ready();  //method inside your custom fragment code
       }
   }
 }
```

Add an interface class:

```
public interface ReadyInterface {
   public void ready();
}
```

Implement that interface in your fragments:

```
public class ReadyFragment extends Fragment implements ReadyInterface {

  //.. your regular fragment stuff

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
    }
 }
 ...
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    //Save the fragment's state here
  }

   @Overide
   public void ready() { 
     // do your stuff here that needs to happen 
     //once fragment is displayed and running
   }

}
```

Comment: The answer explains how to know definitely when a fragment is running and on display.  View pager destroy and create fragments continuously.

Comment: I added the stuff for save and restore fragment state

Comment: Can you help me utilize this logic for this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134470/recyclerview-in-fragment-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, after you set the adapter for the view pager, put your code for whatever on the onPageSelected() method. It is called everytime you change or swipe the viewPager.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```