# Static buttons under a ScrollView with a dynamic tablelayout within it

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a dynamic table that can have as few as 2 rows but can also have upto 50 rows. I am trying to wrap that table within a scrollview. I also need to have 2 buttons that should show up at the bottom of the page.

Here is what I am trying to achieve but am getting stuck (attached the images to show what I am trying):

1. If there are few rows, there shouldnt be a scroll view and the table should appear with the buttons just below the table.
2. If there are more than x number of rows, wrap that table in a scrollview with a max height and then show the buttons at the bottom at a static place. The table scrolls but the buttons disappear below the scrollview.

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong ? I scanned through a lot of questions on StackOverflow but couldnt find something that addresses this particular situation.

**Below is my layout file and I populate the table in the activity :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mainTable">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="425dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Submit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Table and buttons appear fine when there are few rows]

[image: Max Height for the table with buttons]

[image: Buttons Disappear]

[image: RelativeLayout]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider using a `RecyclerView` instead of a `TableLayout` within a `ScrollView`. If you can set a static height for your button view layout you can manipulate the padding and margins to get the desired effect. See below modified from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45161728/6723646

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="45dp">
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mainTable">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-45dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Submit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @airfish. I am not sure how to align a table layout with a recyclerview and attach it dynamically from an activity.

Comment: I suppose you could use the same concept with your `TableLayout` embedded in the `ScrollView` instead of the `RecyclerView` above. The `ScrollView` would have the same properties as the `RecyclerView` and the `TableLayout` would stay the same.

Comment: Tried this - one problem - the scroll bar appears right next to the second column instead of being to the extreme right.

Comment: Try making the scrollview width match parent and table layout with layout gravity center in parent

Comment: Thanks @airfish - you nailed it....This was amazing....Just one more help needed ! I need the bottom two buttons to align to the center next to each other no matter how I align the screen - potrait or landscape.

Comment: Right now, I am manually padding to the left to move the buttons to the center of a horizontal screen which is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @airfish and @Onik for your solutions. The solution from @airfish helped resolve my issue finally, after struggling with it for the past 2 days.

Here is the final solution, for anyone interested in getting this to work.

**Final Layout File.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="45dp">
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/mainTable">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-45dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Submit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java (Edit Line # 30 to increase/decrease the number of rows for testing)**

```
package com.example.scroll_ex;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TableLayout mainTable = findViewById(R.id.mainTable);

        mainTable.removeAllViews();

        int leftRowMargin = 0;
        int topRowMargin = 0;
        int rightRowMargin = 0;
        int bottomRowMargin = 0;
        int textSize = 0, smallTextSize = 0, mediumTextSize = 0;

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView column1 = new TextView(this);
        TextView column2 = new TextView(this);

        for(int i=-1; i < 25; i++){

            tr = new TableRow(this);
            column1 = new TextView(this);
            column2 = new TextView(this);

            tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.setId(i+ 1);
            TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            trParams.setMargins(leftRowMargin, topRowMargin, rightRowMargin, bottomRowMargin);
            tr.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            tr.setLayoutParams(trParams);

            if (i == -1) {
                column1.setText("Name");
                column1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                column1.setPadding(5, 5, 1, 5);
            } else {
                column1.setText("Name #" + i);
                column1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                column1.setPadding(5, 0, 1, 5);
            }

            tr.addView(column1);


            if (i == -1) {
                column2.setText("Address");
                column2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                column2.setPadding(5, 5, 1, 5);
            } else {
                column2.setText("Address " + i);
                column2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                column2.setPadding(5, 0, 1, 5);
            }

            tr.addView(column2);
            mainTable.addView(tr, trParams);
        }

    }
}
```

[image: Scroll with buttons]

[image: No Scroll]